# text not displaying in html angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi trying to display the text which is coming from the controller scope.

Here what have tried:

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in sResults"></div>
```

Controller JS:

```
$scope.sResults = [];
function App( ){
            var Label = ‘a’;
            var demo = [“a”,”b”,’c’,’d’];

            jQuery.each( demo, function( index, value) {
                debugger;
                if(scopeLabel==value){
                    debugger;
                    $scope.sResults.push(value);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: You are not printing item into the html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not printing item into the html

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in sResults">{{item}}</div>
```